# PubSub Server Example: How are messages broadcast?

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe

I'm working on the Node.js in Action book and I'm a bit confused about their PubSub server example in chapter 3. The example allows users to connect to the server via telnet and broadcast messages to each other. Here's the code:

```
var events = require('events')
    , net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join', function(id, client) {
  this.clients[id] = client; 
  this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId, message) {
    if (id != senderId) { 
      this.clients[id].write(message);
    }
  }
  this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]); 
});

channel.on('leave', function(id) { 
  channel.removeListener('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]); 
  channel.emit('broadcast', id, id + " has left the chat.\n");
});

channel.on('shutdown', function() {
  channel.emit('broadcast', '', "Chat has shut down.\n");
  channel.removeAllListeners('broadcast');
});

var server = net.createServer(function (client) {
  var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
  client.on('connect', function() {
    channel.emit('join', id, client); 
  });
  client.on('data', function(data) {
    data = data.toString();
    if (data == "shutdown\r\n") {
      channel.emit('shutdown');
    }
    channel.emit('broadcast', id, data); 
  });
  client.on('close', function() {
    channel.emit('leave', id); 
  });
});
server.listen(8888);
```

This seems pretty clear cut. `client.on('data',function(data){...` is clearly the binding for a client submitting a message after which `channel.emit...` takes care of broadcasting BUT I can't figure out how that message is then broadcast to all other users. To me it seems one would have to loop through all clients in `clients{}` but that's not how the code handles it. Can anyone explain to me what happens after `channel.emit('broadcast'...` so that the data is broadcast to all clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client connects, 'join' is emitted. In the 'join' event handler is `this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);`. This sets up a new (additional) 'broadcast' event handler that writes whatever was broadcasted to the newly connected client. So when a client sends data to the server, 'broadcast' is emitted which triggers the 'broadcast' event handler for every client connected which in turn writes that broadcasted data to each connected clients.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is the broadcast event handler built in so just setting it for the `join` event is all that needs to be accounted for?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "built in", but a new broadcast event handler is created/added for each new client. This only needs to be done once and is done on 'join' because that is called exactly once for each new client.

Comment: My confusion is that an event handler seems to typically take the form `object.on('event', function(){...}` whereas here it's just of the form `this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);`. I'm not sure where the action is taking place so to speak. How is the handler for broadcast using only `this.subscriptions[id]` to actually print the data to the channel? Is that built in functionality and therefor doesn't need to be coded?

Comment: The event handler function stored as `this.subscriptions[id]` is set right above there with `this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId, message) {`. It's just passing in a function stored in a variable instead of passing it inline as an anonymous function.